# Split the list in large dataframe to columns in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

I have the following dataframe.

```
    0
0   [121, Issued, 10112]
1   [121, Assigned, 10112]
2   [121, Completed, 10112]
3   [121, Issued, 10113]
4   [121, Completed, 10113]
5   [121, Assigned, 10113]
6   [121, Completed, 10113]
.
.
200
```

With above 300 rows.

It's easy to separate when we have limited rows.
How do we separate the large dataframe's row list into three columns.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Can you provide more details e.g what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.

```
    col = df.iloc[:, 0].to_list()
    column_list = []
    for i in range(len(df)):
        column_list.append(list(map(lambda x:x[i],col)))
    df = pd.DataFrame(column_list).T
    print(df)
```

Output:

```
         0          1      2
    0  121     Issued  10112
    1  121   Assigned  10112
    2  121  Completed  10112
```